# Creating a sound in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

I am using the following that I pulled out of a tutorial to help me play a quick sound in my game, but I will be using this very often to play sounds. Should I be doing anything different? or is this a proper way to play a sound effect.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound/Microwave_Bell_Ding" ofType:@"mp3"];    
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) pathURL, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thats very fine to play system sounds. Dont worry about it

Comment: Sure that is one of the four ways to reproduce sound. It's the most high level solution. The other ways you can manipulate bytes but if there is no need i don't recomend you. What you wrote works fine

Comment: So even if i played 1000+ sounds like this it should be ok?

Comment: ?  what are you worried about?  I do not think ti will leak, if thats what you mean.  If you mean performance wise, 1000 at a time is not going to happen.

Comment: nono of course not 1000 at a time, just 1000 over the course of 1 game

Answer (score 0):

first,you can't play mp3 in this way.second,you can store soundID,when you play next time,just call AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);